# How to use re.compile python

Tags: python, regex, compilation

I have the following function and I;m trying to think of a way of using re.compile to pre-compile the regex. I'm wondering how to use re.compile in the context of a function with a for loop, changing every line.

```
def ChangeMode(file, amode0, amode1, bmode0, bmode1):
    for line in iter(file):
        if 'AAA' in line or 'BBB' in line or 'CCC' in line:
                line = re.sub(mode0, mode1, line)
                line = re.sub(bmode0, bmode1, line)
        endstring += line
return endstring
```

Comment: Python caches regexes anyway, you don't need to explicitly compile them.

Comment: in this case, is it possible to optimise the re.sub lines at all? or any quicker way of doing it?

Comment: What's the actual *problem* you're trying to solve here? If you have a real performance issue, have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: Trying to replace text in lines in a file. It takes quite a long time on a 10mb file, so trying to speed it up. Struggling to use profiling in python 2.5 :/

Comment: Then... stop using 2.5?

Comment: Sorry, I can't it's inbuilt with the program I'm using :/

Comment: Without profiling you're just guessing at the issues, even if you can find the hotspots on a newer version then port them back to 2.5 at least you're not fumbling around in the metaphorical dark.